# getting error "undefined is not iterable" in BarChart in react.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bar-chart

I am getting an error in `BarChart`:

> undefined is not iterable!

The response I am getting from API is:

```json
{
  "saleCharts": [
    {
      "priceSum": 0,
      "categoryName": "string"
    }
  ],
  "statusCharts": [
    {
      "qtySum": 0,
      "status": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I have written in `React` is:

```js
function Dashboard({ notifyData }) {

    const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState([]);
    const [dashboardData, setDashboardData] = useState([]);
    const [newOrderCount, setNewOrderCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {

        getNewOrder();
    }, [notifyData]);

    var getNewOrder = function () {
        let orderResp = [];
        axios.get(GetNewOrdersUrl + '/2').then(response => {
            orderResp = response.data;
        })
            .then(() =>
                axios.get(OrderDashboardUrl).then(response => {
                    setOrderData(orderResp.orderList);
                    setNewOrderCount(orderResp.count);
                    setDashboardData(response.data.saleCharts);

                }))
    };
}
return (
    <>
        <BarChart
            xAxis={[
                {
                    id: 'barCategories',
                    data: dashboardData.map(item => item.categoryName),
                    scaleType: 'band',
                },
            ]}
            series={[
                {
                    data: dashboardData.map(item => item.priceSum),
                },
            ]}
            colors={['#d75b47']}
            width={1000}
            height={350}
        />
    </>
)
```

Please suggest why I getting that problem and provide the solution.
What I understand is the `BarChart` component is rendering first before the state.

Comment: Have you tried logging out the value of `response.data.saleCharts` as you `setDashboardData` to make sure it's the expected value? Other than that, I can't see any obvious reason this error would occur.

Comment: logging out means? can you elaborate?

Comment: You can try to set a default value to `dashboardData` state like: `const [dashboardData, setDashboardData] = useState([ { priceSum: 0} ]);`

Comment: You can review and test it here easily: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4p5zsq?file=Demo.tsx, when you remove the default state, then you get the error

Comment: @LeelKumar You're welcome! Let me post an answer, so you can approve it and get the reputation. It also might be helpful for someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the `series` prop of the `BarChart` component. It requires the `series` prop describing the data to render. The `series` prop gets an array and should include the data objects. None of the data objects shouldn't have any undefined values. See: [BarChart Documentation](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/getting-started/#single-charts)

Therefore, there can be applied two solutions to prevent this issue.

1. Set a default state to `dashboardData` state:

```
const [dashboardData, setDashboardData] = useState([ { priceSum: 0 } ]);
```

2. Render the `BarChart` component only when the `dashboardData` state has values. Therefore, it will not be rendered in the first render since `dashboardData` has no length:

```
return (
   !!dashboardData.length && (
      <BarChart ... />
   )
);
```

Here is [DEMO LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4p5zsq?file=Demo.tsx) to test and review it easily.

Hope, it's helpful and clear for anyone who needs it.